# Why is the reactive state a constant in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to learn Vue.js and was following the official guides. On the [Reactivity Fundamentals](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-methods) tutorial I found out that the state, which is initialized as a reactive variable, is declared as a constant. Why are they doing this and why is this working?

```
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const state = reactive({ count: 0 })

function increment() {
  state.count++
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="increment">
    {{ state.count }}
  </button>
</template>
```

Comment: hint: it's `state.count` that is being changed, not `state`

Comment: The linked answer does not apply to Vue. Vue's [reactivity](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) uses [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which are a bit different.

Comment: but a "const" is still a "const" - and I think that's the part the OP is having trouble with